# Sending mails in Rails 4.2.0 and detect bounces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

Are there any compftable gems for Rails 4.2.0 to send mails? at the moment I'm using action_mailer, but There is no way to detect bounces?

I want a mail function that have a return value (true/false or something) where I can figure out if the mail was send or not

Is there any way to get a return status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `raise_delivery_errors` to `true` in development made to see if mail are being sending properly or not. (`config/envionments/development.rb`)

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

In development mode to check if mail are being delivered or not you can also use [letter_opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) gem. 
If everything goes well then his gem will open you mail in firefox window.

It's not delivering any mail to real email but it show mail in browser.
This gem is also helpful in designing email templates on the go.

Answer (score 2):

Rails or any gem wont provide this out of the box. You have to check with the mail provider you are using to send the email.

For example you may use Sendgrid or Postmark for sending your emails, postmark has an api via which you can track the bounce also hook it your app to update the status of the emails.

Postmark gem has good utility methods to interact with postmark api and deduce the bounces-reports, etc

Check here - [postmark gem](https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-gem#working-with-bounces)

http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-api-bounce.html